# Cómo resuelvo este error al añadir bean en applicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

Cuando creo un nuevo bean en mi archivo aplicationContext.xml me manda este error,

`Spring. Bean property 'subscriberDAO' is not writable`

La edición del archivo es:

```
<bean id="subscriberDAO"
    class="com.teknoui.mx.client.dao.subscriber.SubscriberDAOImpl">
    <property name="subscriberDAO" ref="subscriberDAO" />
</bean>
<bean id="subscriberService"
    class="com.teknoui.mx.client.service.subscriber.SubscriberServiceImpl">
    <property name="subscriberDAO" ref="subscriberDAO" />
</bean>
```

La traza del error es

> Error creating bean with name 'subscriberDAO' defined in class path
>   resource [applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'subscriberDAO' of bean class
>   [com.teknoui.mx.client.dao.subscriber.SubscriberDAOImpl]: Bean
>   property 'subscriberDAO' is not writable or has an invalid setter
>   method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of
>   the getter?

Comment: Revisa que las clases tengan sus getters / setters correctamente formados. Y los constructores por defecto / con parámetros indicados. Te recomiendo utilizar alguna herramienta como **Lombok** que te facilita la generación de métodos básicos y deja el código más legible.

Comment: @user151683 agrega por favor tu clase: SubscriberDAOImpl

Answer (score 0):

Estas definiendo en la clase `SubscriberDAOImpl` la propiedad

```
<property name="subscriberDAO" ref="subscriberDAO" />
```

debes asegurar tener creado el el setter y getter de esta propiedad y definirlos como publico

```
public void setsubscriberDAO(String subscriberDAO) {
      ...
      ...
  }

  public String getsubscriberDAO() {
      ...
      ...
  }
```